# Blender 3.6+ Animating UV Maps

Tags: animation, uv, shader-nodes

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AE0MwSNZT04) demonstrates a clever way to animate UVs by keyframing the Factor value of a Mix node to smoothly transition between two UV maps. I took it a baby step further by connecting the output of a Value node to the Factor input so I could have the UV transform be driven by the X position of other geometry like an Empty.

It works great in one dimension to animate between two different UV maps. Is it possible to set this up to work in two dimensions, so it's possible to also have the Z position of an empty drive the transition between two additional UV maps? It does not appear to be possible with available Shader Nodes, but might it be possible to recreate this setup with Geometry Nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it is possible to do this with shader nodes and that the answer was very straightforward. The X position drives the horizontal transformations as described above. I created an identical node group so that the Z position drives the vertical transformations. The secret sauce is to take the results of the Mix nodes for the X and Z transforms and feed them into the A & B inputs of a third Mix node.